# Long-polling with Atmosphere issue with Servlet 2.5

Tags: java, websocket, long-polling, atmosphere

I'm testing a simple chat application which is using Atmosphere framework. When I connect to the application from two browsers everything works like chat should work with **Tomcat 7.0** and **Websockets** protocol is used.

When I downgrade to **Tomcat 6.0.** or when I use **Weblogic 10.3.6** long-polling is used (as expected). With one browser chatting with itself everything works but when I open second browser both windows are disconnected.

I set the log level to TRACE and it seems that Atmosphere is adding every **AtmosphereResource** with the same UUID set to 10000:

`TRACE [http-8080-6] o.a.c.DefaultAtmosphereResourceFactory     [DefaultAtmosphereResourceFactory.java:309] Adding: AtmosphereResource{
     uuid=10000,
     transport=LONG_POLLING,
     isInScope=true,
     isResumed=false,
     isCancelled=false,
     isSuspended=true,
     broadcasters=/chat,
     isClosedByClient=false,
     isClosedByApplication=false,
     action=Action{timeout=-1, type=SUSPEND}}`

My Chat.java class:

```
    @AtmosphereHandlerService(path = "/chat", 
broadcasterCache = UUIDBroadcasterCache.class,
                interceptors = {
                        AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor.class,
                        BroadcastOnPostAtmosphereInterceptor.class,
                        SuspendTrackerInterceptor.class,
                        HeartbeatInterceptor.class
                },
                broadcaster = SimpleBroadcaster.class
        )
        public class Chat extends OnMessage<String> {
            private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Chat.class);
            private final JacksonDecoder decoder = new JacksonDecoder();
            private final JacksonEncoder encoder = new JacksonEncoder();


        @Override
        public void onMessage(AtmosphereResponse response, String message) throws IOException {
            Message mes = decoder.decode(message);
            logger.info("{} just send {}", mes.getAuthor(), mes.getMessage());
            response.write(encoder.encode(mes));
        }
```

I'm using **Atmosphere version 2.3.1**.
Unfortunately I need long-polling to work because there Weblogic 10.3.6. installed on our production server and it doesn't support **Websocket** and has implementation of **Servlet 2.5.** only.

**Edit:**

It looks like that during the first GET request to the server, server will set **UUID** for given **AtmosphereRequest** and returns it to the server with HTTP header

**X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=someUUID**

but in the subsequent requsts the client is not using it. It is sending to the server

**X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=10000**

Not sure if this is correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debuggin I was able to resolve this.

The problem was that in my **application.js** library I was using

**trackMessageLength: true**

in request object but there was no TrackMessageSize interceptor defined.

The **Atmosphere.js** library was parsing following array and instead of 1. value it was taking 2.value and setting it as UUID.

["0af719e9-4776-4af1-9925-19c2bb10b547", "10000", "X", "" ]